# how to map the xml tag name in Talend Open studio

Tags: talend

I want to perform on-the-fly transformation from an XML. What talend component can be used to map the below input.xml to output.xml?

input.xml

```
<xom>
    <code1>abc</code1>
    <code2>def</code2>
    <code3>ghi</code3>
</xom>
```

Output.xml

```
<eval>
    <resp>
        <var>code1</var>
        <ans>abc</ans>
    </resp>
    <resp>
        <var>code2</var>
        <ans>def</ans>
    </resp>
    <resp>
        <var>code3</var>
        <ans>ghi</ans>
    </resp>
</eval>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try using the tXmlMap:

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tXMLMap

The help centre at talend is great for this. Let me know if you still have problems and ill knock up and example

Comment: Thanks for your response, Stephen. I tried doing the mapping using tXMLMap and got stuck getting the tag names. If you could help me with an example that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kanb, Due to the schema on the input this was a little harder, the link below should let you download my example, This can be imported to any version 5.4 or grater of the TOS: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvOb9DuQUcMRlZoRHlPQXptS1k

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example  using the tXMLMap](http://www.kindleconsulting.com/blog/item/8-reading-multi-schema-xml-files-with-nested-loops-using-talend-open-studio-part-2-of-3.html).

As shown there, you want to join your 'resp' dataset (using Main) and the 'xom' using a common key that I presume is in both datasets.